# How to add special character using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert a special character dynamically using javascript

₹25

```html
<div class="price"><span>&#8377;</span>25</div>
```

I want to replace above code..here is what i have coded:

```js
var main = document.createElement('div');
main.className = "price";
var abc = document.createElement('span');
var t = document.createTextNode("&#8377;");
abc.appendChild(t);
main.appendChild(abc);
var t1 = document.createTextNode("25"); 
document.body.appendChild(main);
```

How to show this special character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var main = document.createElement('div');
main.className = "price";
var abc = document.createElement('span');
abc.innerHTML="&#8377;";
main.appendChild(abc);
var t1 = document.createTextNode("25"); 
main.appendChild(t1);
document.body.appendChild(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **font-awesome** helps greatly. You can check it out [here](http://fontawesome.io/). Font Awesome gives you scalable vector icons that can instantly be customized — size, color, drop shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of CSS.

Or you can see it in [github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome) also. Font Awesome is a full suite of 634 pictographic icons for easy scalable vector graphics on websites, created and maintained by Dave Gandy. Stay up to date with the latest release and announcements on Twitter: